# NtQueryInformationFile for FileStreamInformation succeeds in 32-bit fails in 64-bit

Tags: windows, smb

Edit: this question was originally about behavioural difference between code in C++ and C# but that proved to be a red herring. Question has been rewritten to better reflect the problem I'm having.

I'm trying to list the alternate streams of a file hosted on an SMB server using the NtQueryInformationFile function. The code I've written so far works correctly with most servers but fails sometimes when run against non-samba Mac OS X SMB server.

I've reduced the code form my application to the following bit of code that reproduces the issue reliably:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace Streams
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public uint dwScope;
            public uint dwType;
            public uint dwDisplayType;
            public uint dwUsage;

            public string lpLocalName;
            public string lpRemoteName;
            public string lpComment;
            public string lpProvider;
        }

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint NtQueryInformationFile(
            SafeFileHandle handle,
            IntPtr IoStatusBlock,
            IntPtr pInfoBlock,
            uint length,
            uint fileInformationClass);


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
            string fileName,
            uint desiredAccessMask,
            uint shareMode,
            IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            uint creationDisposition,
            uint flagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint WNetAddConnection2(NETRESOURCE netResource, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string password, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string username, uint flags);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = args[0];
            var username = args[1];
            var password = args[2];
            var uncPath = args[3];

            NETRESOURCE netResource = new NETRESOURCE();
            netResource.dwType = 0x1 /* DISK */;
            netResource.lpRemoteName = server;
            WNetAddConnection2(netResource, password, username, 0x00000004 /* CONNECT_TEMPORARY */);

            var fh = CreateFile(
                uncPath,
                0x80000000 /* GENERIC_READ */,
                (uint)(FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Delete), 
                IntPtr.Zero,
                3 /* OPEN_EXISTING */,
                0x08000000 /* SequentialScan */ | 0x02000000 /* BackupSemantics */, 
                IntPtr.Zero
                );

            IntPtr status = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
            uint bufferSize = 64*1024;
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bufferSize);

            uint ntStatus = NtQueryInformationFile(fh, status, buffer, bufferSize, 22 /* FileStreamInformation */);

            Console.WriteLine($"NtQueryFileInformation returned {ntStatus}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In most cases the value of ntStatus is STATUS_OK as is expected. When I try to use this on a file that has alternate data streams with a Mac OS X SMB server I get STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE instead. That error code seems to indicate that the response from the server is incorrect, but when I inspect this with Wireshark there are no differences compared to when STATUS_OK is returned.

To make things even stranger, this code works when I run it in 32-bit mode (set the 'Prefer 32-bit' in the Visual Studio project settings). When run in 64-bit mode I always get the error code.
The obvious error then would be that the code in question is not 64-bit clean, but AFAICT the code above is.

I've also tried replacing the NtQueryInformationFile call with the call to GetFileInformationByHandleEx, but that gives me the same result (with a Win32 error code instead of an NT status code of course).

What could explain this difference in behaviour between 32-bit and 64-bit mode?

Comment: Some day I'll figure out why an SO user posts the code that works and hides the code he's having a problem with.  That day is not yet close :(

Comment: Post the actual code that failed, most likely the cause is a bug in the code port to C#. The API itself doesn't cares at all from what language is called, as long as the ABI is respected.

Comment: Ok ok, I didn't post the C# code because it's identical...

Comment: So I've added the C# code except for the enum values. I've also added the packet dumps from Wireshark for completeness. Apologies for not adding this immediately. I didn't feel it added much information since there's so little code and the packet traces are identical. I wanted to keep my question short.

Comment: The C# code discards the handle returned by CreateFile, and passes an uninitialized variable as the handle to NtQueryInformationFile!

Comment: Sigh, that got messed up while I was trying to format the code in the tiny stack overflow edit window; my bad. The code wouldn't have even compiled since fh wasn't just uninitialised; it's not even defined. I need to practice more on asking questions here :) I asure you it's not something that trivial. The correct messages are being sent out over the network with the correct file handle value. The correct response is being sent back in both cases. The only observable difference is the return value.